# Cant get new location after stopUpdatingLocation - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gps, coordinates

I'm trying to get a users GPS coordinates from my app, which works fine, once. When the view gets called I run the code and get the location - good - but when I get back to the view I want NEW coordinates but I only get the old ones like they are chashed in the phone.

Here is my code:

```
#import "PostPictureViewController.h"

@interface PostPictureViewController ()

@end

@implementation PostPictureViewController

{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];           
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self getLocation];
}

-(void)getLocation{
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Fel" message:@"Error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]);
    }
    // Stop Location Manager
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; //This is screwing it up
    locationManager = nil;
}
```

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface PostPictureViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@end
```

I think my problem is the `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];` line where I stop the locationManager after getting the coordinates the first time. I have tried without this line and then it works - updates coordinates - but I dont want the `locationmanager` to send me new coordinates every second. I only need them once per view-time.

Anyone got a clue? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try in this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];   
 locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 [self getLocation];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)getLocation{
 locationManager.delegate = self;
 locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
 UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Fel" message:@"Error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
 NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
 CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

 if (currentLocation != nil) {
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]);
 }
 // Stop Location Manager
 [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; //This is screwing it up
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
 locationManager = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its not working 100%, it updates every other time(?) and when i just go back one step and them forward to the view again it does not update

Comment: @PaperThick try now, I edited. It will update location every time the view appears and it will stop just after it got it. I understood you want that, is it correct?

Comment: No sorry still the same problem. I updated my question with some additional code but i'm pretty sure it'n not important

Comment: @PaperThick I do not now what are you trying to do but I tested my code and it works correctly. Basically I put that code in one view controller called PostPictureViewController. So when I show the view controller the location is updated and then it stopped. After that if I push a another view controller SuccessPictureViewController from PostPictureViewController and then come back to PostPictureViewController, well the location is updated again. What's wrong with that? Maybe you have to explain better what you want to do.

Comment: Of course if your view controller PostPictureViewController is always on the screen that code is not going to work because `viewWillAppear` is never called again. So in that case you need to change it.

Comment: check out my answer below it explains how to implement it. There's no other way you'll do it

Comment: @art-divin did you see that he wrote "I only need them once per view-time"? So why are you suggesting to use a timer? It doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: @Mr.Frank Thanks you for all your help, I will try to explain as detailed as possible. Basically what I want is ONE NEW coordinate every time this view comes into view, regardless of how you get the view to appear (go back, push, segue, switch to it). I'm really wondering why my code doesn't work since your's work

Comment: @Mr.Frank yeah, thanks, didn't see his "few" part of the question.
2PaperThick: I think the difference between your implementation and Mr.Frank's is the way controller is pushed into hierarchy